# Chinese character in the path using netcdf4 dataset

Tags: python, netcdf

I need to open a nc file with netcdf4. But in the path of the file, there are chinese characters and netCDF4.Dataset return the error : "No such file or directory".
But if I use "os.path.isfile", the file is found. 
I've tried to decode, encode (in utf-8) the path without result.

Is there any option to use in dataset call ?

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a unicode glitch. Can you open an issue at https://github.com/unidata/netcdf4-python/issues?